# How to get table row index when the column textbox value change using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get row index and text box values when the table price text box value changes. At the moment I'm getting some undefined value.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>                   
            <th>Product</th>                              
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control product">
            </td> 
            <td>
                <input type="text" oninput="javascript:GetValue(this);" class="form-control price">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function GetValue(oTextBox) {
    var price = oTextBox.value;
    var product = oTextBox.parent().prev().innerHTML.value;
    var rowindex = oTextBox.closest('tr').index();
}
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: oTextBox.parent is not a function
>   var product = oTextBox.parent().prev().innerHTML.value;

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap `oTextBox` in $ in order to use jQuery methods. That's because `oTextBox` ... or  ... `this` is a DOM element and not a jQuery object. Thus:

```
var product = oTextBox.parent().prev().innerHTML.value;
```

Should be:

```
var product = $(oTextBox).parent().prev().find('input').val();
```

And:

```
var rowindex = oTextBox.closest('tr').index();
```

Should be:

```
var rowindex = $(oTextBox).closest('tr').index();
```

**SUGGESTION**

I would encourage you to not use inline JS:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control price">
```

Then your jQuery would be:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.price').on('input', function() {
        var price = this.value;
        var product = $(this).parent().prev().find('input').val();
        var rowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        //....
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace oTextBox in the function by $(oTextBox) and then you can use html() instead of innerHTML, like so

```
$(oTextBox).parent().prev().html()
```